# Passport / Express Session Auth Breaking When Moving Server to a CORS Location

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, express, cors

I'm building an app with angular.js and ionic.  I moved all the front end app stuff into a package and moved the server logic to it's own droplet on digital ocean. Now the front end has to make CORS.  On the initial authenticate, everything seems to work well except the cookies object on the response from express is empty.

When it worked, sans CORS.  I got this

```
 cookies: { 'connect.sid': 's:ZrKJ7BxH2yeAiFG5uTC2FlhpfCa9S17K.oA5bCUQjZbdJBS8ohzngSiOEFzJWCyKxLDlBdEUqhzk' },
```

Now, when with the server up on a droplet and CORS enabled, I get this from the response

```
  cookies: {},
```

The only thing that can be different is that the request comes from CORS.  The 'env' wasn't set on either one, so they both default to development.

The CORS set up I have is this:

```
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("In allow cross domain function", req.headers)
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
}
```

In chrome developer tools, I never see a cookie land in my resources / cookies tab, but I did before I was doing CORS...  It must be that now the response is being sent back to a different domain right?  I can't think of anything else that would cause passport / express to not work the way it was prior to the 'one-domain' setup.

**Edit**: I'll post the express session code too, even though this was working before moving the server.

```
app.use(session({
    secret: app.getValue('env').SESSION_SECRET,
    store: new MongoStore({mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection}),
    cookie: { maxAge: 60000, secure: false },
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    console.log('Passport serializing user =>', user)
    done(null, user._id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    console.log('Received this id => ', id)
    UserModel.findById(id, done);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set wildcard for origin for requests that contain cookies.

[CORS with credentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Requests_with_credentials)

> Important note: when responding to a credentialed request,  server must specify a domain, and cannot use wild carding.  The above example would fail if the header was wildcarded as: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *.

Also as the link notes, you'll need to set `withCredentials: true` to your AJAX request.

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware of this being the case, and even though there were a few other questions this wasn't mentioned there.  So if my client comes from an app -- (aka, everyone has a different device and thereby origin, can I NOT rely on cookies?) There's no ONE domain I could put in here correct? That's why I was wildcarding to begin with.

Comment: technically correct. I think it would be possible to hack it and set your allow-origin header dynamically based on the request origin. something like `res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', parseRequestForOrigin() );` . I'm not sure what the security implications are though.